# angular-nvd3 margin doesn't work? (krispo)

Tags: angular-nvd3

No matter how much I change the margin. [The dates get cut off](http://prntscr.com/fls9vv). I am trying to show a 7 date range, but the last date gets cut off. Any ideas, to work around this?

My code:

```
vm.lineChartOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'lineChart',
        height: 450,
        tickPadding: 25,
        margin: {
            top: 50,
            right: 1000,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 1000
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a property in the xAxis object, and I had the showMaxMin: set to false, and changed it to true. I also realized my gulp wasn't running for about an hour so there's that.

After I set to showMaxMin to true, and booted my gulp up again, I was able to change the margin.